# Android Bluetooth Broadcast Receiver Issues with ACL_CONNECTED and AC_DISCONNECTED in android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I am writing an broadcast receiver that detects whether or not a bluetooth device is connected.
here is my bluetooth broadcast receiver :

```
 val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
            addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
        }
        this.registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, filter)


private val broadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action = intent?.action
        when (action) {
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED -> {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    delay(6000)
                    deviceHelper.configAudioManager(true, true)
                }
            }

            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED -> {
                deviceHelper.configAudioManager(false, true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works on all Androids without any problems. But in Android version 12, if a Bluetooth handsfree is connected to the Android phone, the broadcast receiver is not called at all, while it works well in all other Androids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May require BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission.
Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice?hl=zh-cn#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED

Comment: yes require handle runtime permission for  android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, thanks